Dynamic SQL for DB2
The below SQL query is not fetching columns into v_columns. When I print v_columns it is NULL always
SET v_sql = 'SELECT LISTAGG(COLNAME , '','') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLNO) INTO :v_columns ' || 'FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS ' || 'WHERE TABNAME = ''' || v_tableName || ''' AND COLNAME <> ''TOWID''';


What platform and version of Db2?
For Db2 for IBM i, SELECT INTO can not be run dynamically.  Instead you have to use VALUES INTO.  A quick check on the Db2 LUW docs shows the same restriction.

Invocation
This statement can be embedded only in an application program. It is
an executable statement that cannot be dynamically prepared.


The VALUES INTO statement can't be used dynamically as well: "This statement can be embedded only in an application program. It is an executable statement that cannot be dynamically prepared."

Interestingly, it can be dynamic on Db2 for IBM i "This statement can be embedded in an application program. It is an executable statement that can be
dynamically prepared,"

Use the SET statement instead.
BEGIN
  DECLARE v_sql VARCHAR(1000);
  DECLARE v_cols VARCHAR(32000);
  DECLARE v_tableName VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT 'COLUMNS';

  SET v_sql = 
     'SET ? = (SELECT LISTAGG(COLNAME , '','') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLNO) ' 
  || 'FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS '
  || 'WHERE TABNAME = ''' || v_tableName || ''' AND COLNAME <> ''TOWID'')';

  PREPARE S1 FROM v_sql;
  EXECUTE S1 INTO v_cols;
END@

Note, that you should use filter on TABSCHEMA as well querying the SYSCAT.COLUMNS view.
